# Porting Func based binding from Ninject to TinyIOC

Tags: .net, ninject

Could anyone help with porting the following binding from Ninject to [TinyIOC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC):

```
Bind<Func<Type, IJob>>().ToConstant(type => (IJob)Kernel.Get(type));
```

Comment: In case the answer below isn't what you're after can you explain how that registration behaves in ninject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used TinyIOC, but you could try the following.

```
container.Register<Func<Type, IJob>>(type => (IJob)container.Resolve(type));
```

Comment: Weird, when I initially came up with exactly that I had intellisense complaining about a mismatch. Must have been a typo. Thanks anyway.